# Add html content to Microsoft SQL Server database asp net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I want to add html content into a SQL Server database.

For example, on a label it is shows location coordinates, and after button click it will be added in SQL Server. I have gone so far but every time I click on the button it is added in the database empty, not coordinates.

I will give the source code...

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="tripmeter" runat="server">
        <p runat="server">
            Starting Location (lat, lon):<br />
            <span id="startLat" runat="server"></span>&deg;, <span id="startLon" runat="server"></span>&deg;
        </p>
        <p runat="server">
            Current Location:<br />
            <label id="currentLat" runat="server"></label>&deg;, <span id="currentLon" runat="server"></span>&deg;
        </p>
        <p runat="server">
            Distance from starting location:<br />
            <span id="distance" runat="server">0</span> km
        </p>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" runat="server" onserverclick="MySubmitHandler" />
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
        var startPos;

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                startPos = position;
                document.getElementById("startLat").innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
                document.getElementById("startLon").innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
            }, function (error) {
                alert("Error occurred. Error code: " + error.code);
                // error.code can be:
                //   0: unknown error
                //   1: permission denied
                //   2: position unavailable (error response from locaton provider)
                //   3: timed out
            });

            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
                document.getElementById("currentLat").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
                document.getElementById("currentLon").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
                document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML =
                  calculateDistance(startPos.coords.latitude, startPos.coords.longitude,
                                    position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            });
        }
    };
    function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        var R = 6371; // km
        var dLat = (lat2 - lat1).toRad();
        var dLon = (lon2 - lon1).toRad();
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) *
                Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c;
        return d;
    }
    Number.prototype.toRad = function () {
        return this * Math.PI / 180;
    }
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void MySubmitHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection lidhje = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            lidhje.Open();
            string fut = "insert into Test (lat) values (@lat)";
            SqlCommand komande = new SqlCommand(fut, lidhje);
            komande.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lat", currentLat.InnerText);

            komande.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Success");

            lidhje.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set datatype Text in your database;

eg:

```
    create table temp(
    linkId int(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    htmlValue Text(200) NULL); // this will store your data in HTML format.
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: So what, if it is, then DB is going to change with NOSQL, or BIG DATA Problem is implementing using hadoop and more very high technologies....